# Block SQL 2008 R2 Insert Access on anything for user in MS ACCESS on AD Group

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-access

Hi I would like to block access to insert any data on SQL when a User from a determined Active Directory Group access SQL from MS ACCESS.

Is this possible?
if not is there any alternative?

I've tried a server trigger, and was able to prevent access to sql from someone by its IP, and the program name. But I would like to prevent inserts, is there a way to do this?

thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: ONLY from within Access?  Does that group need to be able to INSERT from other places?

Comment: Hmmm probably they have access through win applications but they can be filtered, but yes the app has to be filtered. (I know access is impossible as the application name is office, so office is ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block for an AD user or group. But not *reliably* by client used.

Note: Permissions are for principals, not for code generally.

The client name can determined by [sys.sysprocesses.program_name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx).

### **BUT**

This is set by [`Application Name`](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/use-application-name-sql-server) in the connection string, so it can be any value. And you can't set it in MS Access (upto version 2003 at least): it shows as "Microsoft Office 2003" same as, say, Excel (you can set it from Excel oddly).

So, no, you can't do it.

Comment: so I can only block from a certain AD group ... thanks